# Difference in two datasets

Tags: math, statistics, dataset, compare

My input consists of `x` and `y`and the output is the corresponding `z`. My datasets of course consists of multiple `x,y,z`. The first dataset I will define as `data_1` and the other on as `data_2`. Now, I would like to compare these two datasets regarding the difference of their ouputs `z_1`, `z_2` .

**Question**: How could I describe the difference of `data1 and data2` in **%** ? If the percentage description is not suitable, how could I describe the difference in a global way so that the description does not account just one *z difference* but all the `z` in datasets?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the average z eg: Average(z_1) of all datasets.

Comment: Image z_1 =[0,100] and z_2=[50,50]. By averaging the datasets will be identified as same.